# Prove that $a_1 > (a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4)/4$ implies $a_i < (a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4)/4$ for $i \in \{2, 3, 4\}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Given real numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$, if $a_1 > (a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4)/4$ , then there exists $i \in \{2, 3, 4\}$ such that $a_i < (a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4)/4$.

I could solve the problem in my mind, but I can't put the solution on the paper. I just have difficulty in writing the solution of the question.

Comment: Are you asking for a proof of this? All I see is a sentence. Also, you should move the actual question to the body of the post. And if you can "solve the problem in [your] mind", you should at least try to explain how you did so in the post.

Comment: Just to be clear, is it $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4/4$ or $\frac{a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4}{4}$?

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing parentheses around some parts?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking for a proof. I forgot to use parentheses where it should be like (a1+a2+a3+a4)/4 at both of the inequality. Sorry for asking lack of information.

Comment: suppose it is not true.  Quickly you will run into a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Suppose not. Then we have
$$a_2 \ge \frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4}4$$
and the same for $a_3$ and $a_4$. Now add up $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4$ and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot.